# SMD LED power supply

Tags: led, power, resistors, surface-mount

I bought some SMD LEDs like the ones in the picture, supplied by a 12 V adapter. I wanted to supply them individually for a project so i cut them and soldered to a 18 ohm resistor. I calculated its value with an online calculator. The power supply had 3 v and the LEDs needed 50 ma and 2.1 v, as the site said because they are yellow. The shop where i bought the resistors only had 0.5 W ones. After i soldered the LEDs i saw that they aren't as bright as they were when plugged at a 12v supply. What is the problem?[image]

Comment: Soldered to a 18 Ohm resistor ... well, in which-manner? series? parallel?  in what circuit? Did you considered the LED's internal resistance? LED's resistance, wattage etc does not very-much depend on its color. Rather, same-colored LED of various size, wattage etc. found.

Comment: Omg so many questions!! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LEDs originally were supplied with more than 50mA, or the LED forward voltage is higher than 2.1V. The only way to make a given LED brighter is drive more current through it!

Comment: Ok thank you but how much current? I don't want to burn the LEDs

Comment: No idea. Need a model number, or data sheet for the LEDs, the original assembly, or other information to base an answer on. I also can't see the picture you refer to in your question.

Comment: Yes... i forogot to add it...

Comment: Connect a single segment to 12V. Measure the voltage across a led, and across the resistor. Then measure the resistance of the resistor.  I = V / R. There you have the current through the led and it's forward voltage at that current.

Comment: Those LEDs strips already include a current limiting resistor, so I'm wondering if you actually unsoldered the individual SMD LEDS? If you didn't, then they are dimmer because you're running a 12V strip with 3V, not to mention adding an additional series resistor.

Answer (score -1):

You did-not explained your circuit-structure, and also didnot gave any circuit diagram. I guess such a circuit, with a source of 3V after connected to this particular circuit, an 18 ohms resistor, and a Light-Emitting-Diode (LED) in series. **are-you doing such-thing?**

[image: Supposed circuit]

( abbreviation R.D. used *here* to indicate **R**esistance of the **D**iode in forward bias)

if so, **you could test by removing 18 Ohms resistor, instead using more lower-resistance value**, and doing the test solely with LED. seemingly it would pass more current and glow better.

Also, if you combine more-than-1 LED; in either **series or parallel**; you would **require more voltage** than to glow single-one.

Also, what are you doing with those 0.5 W (Watt?) resistors? Are they same to the previously-mentioned 18 Ohms resistor? (i.e. have you used only single-type (18 Ohm, 0.5W) resistors?) or you are mentioning about 2-set of resistor?

Analog electronic-parts, usually work within a **range-of voltage etc**. Not in only 1 particular, pin-point voltage.  **So you can obviously test by altering the voltages**.

Comment: Yes that's the circuit. They are the same resistors.

Comment: Sorry i can't explain very well. I'm a begginer

Comment: I would recommend you not try testing by removing the 18Ω resistor entirely. You could easily drive enough forward current to damage the LED. You can try reducing the resistance, but not to 0.

Comment: Thanking to @AndyW . But if I remove the series resistor(current limiter), and on same-time lower the voltage to 1.5V or 2V; would the LED be damaged?

Comment: Also to @AndyW I've also seen, from a set of green, non-SMD   small-sized LED (with higher-resistance and dimmer-light), Each individual LED tend to require higher voltage; and they often do-not light-up even in 1.5 V. They require 3 Volt (direct, without resistor) to show some faint light, and a 4.5 Volt to Light up properly. However a 6V was overheating them, with a slight-distortion of color, whereas with a resistor in series (I forgot the value... it was possibly 150 Ohms) it lit-up properly on 6V to 7.5V . (As the voltage-source, 1.5V to 12 V Battery Eliminator (BEC) was used).

Comment: @ Cosmin ... I'm also beginner, in literal sense, (not in higher-sense).  However, keep it up.

Comment: Most LEDs will require at least 1.5V forward voltage. This can vary widely by colour, type, and temperature. See here: http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2011/nov/overcoming-the-technical-challenges-in-implementing-a-driver-based-method-for-detecting-failed-power. Once you provide enough voltage to forward bias, the current increases rapidly (exponentially, actually) with forward voltage, so it's easy to quickly overload the LED with relatively small voltage increases beyond nominal forward bias.

Comment: This is why you should always have a current limiting resistor in series. Check out this page: http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/DT089_Physical_Computing_1/LEDS/Leds.htm